# CreateFile() Serial Communication Issue

Tags: c++, serial-communication, createfile, getlasterror

I am trying to do some serial communication through my usb port (named COM15), and I am getting an error. This is the code where the error is occurring:

```
HANDLE myPortHandle = CreateFile("COM15",
                                  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                  0,
                                  NULL,
                                  OPEN_EXISTING,
                                  0,
                                  NULL);

if (myPortHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    cout<<"ERROR HERE! = "<<lastError<<endl;
}
```

Every time I compile the program, the handle to the opened serial port == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. I read in the CreateFile() msdn documentation to use GetLastError() in order to get "extended error information". Now... when I run the code, GetLastError() returns a value of: 2

In the msdn documentation of GetLastError(), it says:

"The Return Value section of the documentation for each function that sets the last-error code notes the conditions under which the function sets the last-error code."

I tried looking for the meaning of the '2' in the Return Value section of the CreateFile() msdn documentation and couldn't find the meaning anywhere.

**QUESTION:**

1) Why is this happening: myPortHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE?

2) Also, if anyone could direct me to where I need to look in the msdn documentation to find the meaning of the '2' returned by GetLastError(), that would be awesome!

Comment: Search the web for working code, you are not inventing anything new.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I did actually. I just was unlucky enough to find code that all used COM1 through COM9. Issue has been solved thou.

Comment: This is a dupe a hundred times over, sadly neither Google nor SO search can match `\\.\COM` as an exact phrase

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Windows error codes are documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx

Your error code is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Which means that `COM15` cannot be found. According to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/115831/en-gb?wa=wsignin1.0) you need to use the name: `"\\\\.\\COM15"`.

> `CreateFile()` can be used to get a handle to a serial port. The
>   "Win32 Programmer's Reference" entry for "CreateFile()" mentions that
>   the share mode must be 0, the create parameter must be OPEN_EXISTING,
>   and the template must be NULL.
>
> CreateFile() is successful when you use "COM1" through "COM9" for the
>   name of the file; however, the message `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is
>   returned if you use "COM10" or greater.
>
> If the name of the port is `\\.\COM10`, the correct way to specify the
>   serial port in a call to CreateFile() is as follows:
>
> ```
> CreateFile(
>   "\\\\.\\COM10",     // address of name of the communications device
>   fdwAccess,          // access (read-write) mode
>   0,                  // share mode
>   NULL,               // address of security descriptor
>   OPEN_EXISTING,      // how to create
>   0,                  // file attributes
>   NULL                // handle of file with attributes to copy
> );
> ```
>
> NOTES: This syntax also works for ports COM1 through COM9. Certain boards will let you choose the port names yourself. This
>   syntax works for those names as well.

Or alternatively from the documentation to [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) itself:

> The CreateFile function can create a handle to a communications
>   resource, such as the serial port COM1. For communications resources,
>   the dwCreationDisposition parameter must be OPEN_EXISTING, the
>   dwShareMode parameter must be zero (exclusive access), and the
>   hTemplateFile parameter must be NULL. Read, write, or read/write
>   access can be specified, and the handle can be opened for overlapped
>   I/O.
>
> To specify a COM port number greater than 9, use the following syntax:
>   `\\.\COM10`. This syntax works for all port numbers and hardware that
>   allows COM port numbers to be specified.

Comment: Your awesome. If anyone says otherwise then they are lying to you.

Comment: Writing a duplicate answer is not awesome :(  Doesn't change that David is awesome.

Comment: @Ben None of my searches led to SO questions. Sorry.

Comment: I am also having the same problem. The only difference in my case is instead of a real serial port I am using "socat" (cygwin, also if I cat to this file, could see the file throws legit data) command to create a file. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: @SH' If it is the same problem, then the solution is here

Comment: I forgot to say, my code is in C. I tried this solution except fdwAccess using GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE. But it throws error code 2 :(

Comment: @SH' You'll want to ask a new question. Make sure you provide a clean [mcve].